# Visual Studio 2012 Not Recognizing Existing Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I previously created a Unit Test Project then removed it from my solution temporarily. Now that I have added it back, my unit tests aren't being detected by Visual Studio and I can't figure out how to run them.

I was looking online and I saw that there are some solutions regarding the "Test Tools" settings, but it seems to have been removed in VS 2012.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How can I fix it so I can run my unit tests again?

Comment: When you say aren't being detected, what do you mean?  You can't right click within a method and say "Run Tests"?

Comment: I meant that it didn't show up in the Test Explorer and if I clicked "Run All" or rebuilt the solution, none of them would be run/added to the Test Explorer.

Comment: I just had this issue and it was because my test class was not `public`

Comment: in my case, I downgrade Nunit to lower version (3. -> 2.6) and it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible cause, mentioned in the comments by [AH.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330420/ah) and [Johnathon Sullinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815321/johnathon-sullinger) is an incorrect signature of asynchronous unit tests - the return type must be a task and cannot be void.

---

Also make sure the test project is checked in the appropriate build configuration:

Go to the *Configuration Manager* and tick the check box for your test project under your current build configuration. Make sure to rebuild the solution afterwards (as correctly pointed out by [Dustin Venegas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61570/dustin-venegas) in the comments).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any .SUO files in your solution folder.  These files are automatically created when Visual Studio loads your solution and are a potential cause for Tests not showing up in the Test Explorer after you build.  I'm assuming you have built your project already.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, for me it seems to be related to TFS and where my workspace is stored. We keep our 'local' workspaces on file servers rather than local PCs for security reasons.

My unittests stopped appearing in the Test Explorer view this morning, after having been developed without issue and working properly as recently as Friday afternoon.

While I don't have a cause or solution for the problem, I do have a couple of potential workarounds. Either:

- Change the Local Path for the relevant solution in tfs to a local drive. In the Source Control Explorer window click on *Workspace > Workspaces... > Edit...* and then add a new working folder for the solution in question

or:

- Change the output directory for the test project to a local drive. Right click on the project and select properties, then in *Build > Output > Output path*, browse to a local folder