# Unit Tests project stops getting compiled by MSBuild upon moving the solution file

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a **MVC 4** solution and I need to move my solution file from its existing location to its parent. I selected the file in the "**Solution Explorer**" and did "**File->Save As**" and browsed to the parent folder and saved a copy. When I open up the .sln file in Notepad I see that the project refs were correctly updated to point to the new location of the projects with respect to the solution. Now when I build my solution there is no "***.Tests.dll**" file for my test project being generated in my **Startup Project**'s bin folder. I "**Save As**" again back to the old location and the dll gets generated just fine. Is there anything I am missing here? Is this the wrong way to move a solution file?

I am using **MSBuild** to build my solution and run it from Powershell pointing it to the solution file.

Comment: Have you considered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666115/visual-studio-2012-not-recognizing-existing-unit-tests/18667805#18667805 ?

Comment: I mean, that even if you're not building from VS, maybe you should move also the solution settings file?

Comment: Thanks to @BartoszKP for pointing out this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666115/visual-studio-2012-not-recognizing-existing-unit-tests/18667805#18667805